# edit form by removing existing data

Tags: cakephp-2.3

i need to save new edited data by removing existing data for the form but this gives error as user can't be saved while submiting the edited code bt i need to update the field while submitting the form

```
public function provider_edit($id = null) {
        if (!$this->User->exists($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
        if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
            $name =$this->request->data['User']['profile_photo']['name'];
            $tmp_name=$this->request->data['User']['profile_photo']['tmp_name'];
            $filename = WWW_ROOT.'providers_photo/'.$name;
           $random_number = $this->Useful->random_code();
           if(file_exists(WWW_ROOT.'providers_photo/'.$name))
                {
                    $name= $random_number.$this->request->data['User']['profile_photo']['name'];    
                }
            $this->request->data['User']['profile_photo'] = $name;

            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {

                $user_Id = $id;
                    for($i=1;$i<=$this->request->data['User']['rate_count'];$i++){
                        $rate_insert = $this->request->data['User']['rate_'.$i];
                        $rateId = $this->request->data['User']['rate_id_'.$i];
                        if(!empty($rate_insert)){
                            $this->User->query("insert into service_provider_rates
 (user_id,rate_package_id,rate)  values ('$user_Id','$rateId','$rate_insert')");
                         }

                    }

                for($i=1;$i<=$this->request->data['User']['category_count'];$i++){
                    $categories = $this->request->data['User']['category_id_'.$i];

                        if($categories>0){
                            $this->User->query("insert into provider_service_categories
 (user_id,service_categories_id)  values ('$user_Id','$categories')");

                        }

                    }
                if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,WWW_ROOT.'providers_photo'.'\\'.$name))
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
            $this->data =  $this->User->read(null, $id);
        } else {
            $options = array('conditions' => array('User.' . $this->User->primaryKey => $id));
            $this->request->data = $this->User->find('first', $options);

        }


        $ratePackages = $this->User->query("select RP.*,SPR.rate from rate_packages RP left join service_provider_rates SPR on SPR.rate_package_id=RP.id left join users U on U.id=SPR.user_id and U.id={$id} where RP.id is not null group by RP.id");


        $this->loadModel('ServiceCategory');
        $serviceCategories = $this->ServiceCategory->generateTreeList(null,null,null,'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');

        $this->set(compact('categories','serviceCategories','ratePackages'));

        $featureOptions = array('conditions' => array('User.' . $this->User->primaryKey => $id));
        $features = $this->User->find('first', $featureOptions);
        $this->set(compact('features','user_details'));
        $this->render('provider_edit');
    }
```

need to save new edited data for the given id by removing existing one!!!

Comment: Not sure I completely understand - what error is thrown at what point? Have you checked debug($this->request->data) before trying to save it to make sure it looks as it should? Why are you not using the far safer CakePHP saves for your service_provider_rates and provider_service_categories?

Comment: it shows d data while i debug it bt while running the code it dnt enters in here if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {

Comment: And the error? Are you seeing anything with <?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?> and have you set debug mode to 1 or 2 in app/config/core.php - http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#cakephp-core-configuration

Comment: thanx bt i m now able to save the edited data bt i need to delete the data saved using the id in oder database table bt m not able to do so when i use $this->User->delete($user_id ) all the data gets deleted bt new data is not saved so if u have any solution for dat then plz do suggest sumthn

Comment: If your service_provider_rates and provider_service_categories tables/models are related to your User model, you might be able to populate $this->request->data with all three model's required data and then use saveAll http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array. In the past, I've also had to do a deleteAll on an related model and then, if successful, saved the original model and related data with a saveAll, all within a transaction so that the deleteAll is undone if the saveAll fails. All depends on your relationships..

Comment: thanx i managed to do so by implementing some queries